# How to use HBase ColumnRangeFilter by Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

I am considering how to use HBase ColumnRangeFilter by Spark.
I look at [org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableInputFormat.html), but this API does not contain ColumnRangeFilter.
So I do not know how to do ColumnRangeFilter by Spark.

I want to use ColumnRangeFilter that starts with "20170225" and ends with "20170305" for example.

I cound scan Row like under the code.

```
val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, "like_count")
val startRow = "001"
val endRow = "100"
conf.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN_ROW_START, startRow)
conf.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN_ROW_STOP, endRow)
sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, classOf[TableInputFormat], classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable], classOf[Result])
```

What code do I need add?
If anyone have advice, pls tell me about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the scan object to set the start and end row and set that scan object in the Hbase configuration then pass that configuration object to tableInputFormat 
   https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html

```
Scan scan = new Scan(startRow, endRow);
scan.setMaxVersions(MAX_VERSIONS);

//This can also be done if not specified in scan object constructor
scan.setFilter(new ColumnRangeFilter(startrow,true,endrow,true));


HBaseConfiguration.merge(conf, HBaseConfiguration.create(conf));

conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, username + ":" + path);
conf.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN, convertScanToString(scan));


tableInputFormat.setConf(conf);
```

Comment: From where are you getting this `convertScanToString()` function?

Comment: it was a custom method
private static String convertScanToString(Scan scan) {
try {
ClientProtos.Scan proto = ProtobufUtil.toScan(scan);            
return Base64.encodeBytes(proto.toByteArray());
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
return "";
}}

Comment: Thank you so much. I ended up copying the logic from one of HBase classes

Comment: @alina Please upvote the answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: Just did :) Thank you